# How to get an HTML page imitating a desktop device?

Tags: android

I'm trying to parse an HTML page in my app but I get a mobile version of that page without block I need. Is there any way to get the desktop version of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set Headers for your request. I guess, you should set User-Agent header to get full version.

For example, if you use HttpGet, than:

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpParams httpParameters = httpClient.getParams();

HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 8 * 1000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 8 * 1000);

HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
httpGet.addHeader("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0");
```

Answer (score 2):

How are you trying to download the html page? i am guessing with some sort of webview.

if you download it like this, it should have the full content of the desktop version:

```
URL url = new URL("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381617");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
while (true) {
  int ch = r.read();
  if (ch < 0)
    break;
  b.append((char) ch);
}
String s = b.toString();
```

from [Simplest way to correctly load html from web page into a string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381617/simplest-way-to-correctly-load-html-from-web-page-into-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Thanks, but I wanted to get the desktop version of a page and needed to imitate a desktop device.